# Efficient Django querying across models denoting relationships

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-queryset

Suppose I had a Django model like this:

```
class Person(models.Model):
  name = models.CharField(max_length=64, blank=True, null=True)
  age = models.IntField(blank=True, null=True)

class Friendship(models.Model):
  person1 = models.ForeignKey('Person', related_name="person1")
  person2 = models.ForeignKey('Person', related_name="person2”)
```

For Person my_guy, how would I efficiently **find all Persons who aren’t in Friendships with my_guy**?

I can do stuff like this, but there must be a more database-friendly and efficient way:

```
friends = []
for friendship in Friendships.objects.filter(Q(person1=my_guy) | Q(person2=my_guy)):
  if friendship.person1 == my_guy:
    friends.append(friendship.person2)
  else:
    friends.append(friendship.person1)
non_friends = []
for p in Persons.objects.all():
  if p not in friends:
    non_friends.append(p)

print non_friends
```

I’m willing to change the model if need be, though if there’s an efficient way to do this with the existing model, I’d like it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.  The easiest thing was to remake the model with a many-to-many relationship:

```
class Person(models.Model):
  name = models.CharField(max_length=64, blank=True, null=True)
  age = models.IntField(blank=True, null=True)

class Friendship(models.Model):
  members = models.ManyToManyField(Person)
```

Then it was as simple as this:

```
non-friends = Person.objects.exclude(friendship__members=person).exclude(id=person.id)
```